# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and suppose that $Ha=bH$ for $a,b$ elements of $G$. Show that $aH=Hb$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am struggling pretty bad with this homework problem, I've been beating my head against the wall for quite some time and still can't arrive at an answer or even know where to start.

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and suppose that $Ha=bH$ for $a,b$ elements of $G$. Show that $aH=Hb$.

I feel like I'm supposed to apply Lagrange's theorem, but I don't know how...

Comment: you want prove that $aH$ dont depends of the chose of the representant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $a\in Ha=bH$, we have $a=bh$ for some $h\in H$. Therefore, $$aH=(bh)H=b(hH)=bH=Ha.$$
Since $ab^{-1}=h\in H$, we have $Ha=Hb$.
Hence we conclude that $aH=Ha=Hb$.

Comment: I found Rotman's "An Intro to Theory of Groups" 3rd Ed. 1984, *spotty* in some places, where it seems that he makes unproven assertions.  Do you agree?  Did he correct this in a later edition?

Comment: @user2661923 Nope, this is a graduate textbook. So some part of the proof the author will leave as exercises to readers.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the insight.

Comment: Thank you for the response, my friend. I appreciate you taking the time to read my post and help.

Comment: @Kurisu If my answer can help you, please click the tick in my answer to accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @user2661923 Rotman's book, as I recall, mentions (in the intro I think) that a number of proofs are not necessarily fully detailed and rigorous, though he expects many experienced professionals would consider them as such.

Answer (score 0):

A (left or right)  [coset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset#Definition)  is generated by any of its elements.

Therefore $Ha=aH$  ( since $= bH$ a left coset, and contains $a$).

Similarly $bH = Hb$.